# Canceling the remaining time-dependence in a "cyclic" Hamiltonian for which rotating frame transformation (RFT) fails?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, laser-interaction

**Question:** Is there a transformation or simple approximation to use to cancel the time-dependence in a Hamiltonian of form
$$
H_{G} = \sum_{(m,n)\in E,\ m<n}\Omega_{mn} e^{-i\Delta_{mn} t} |m\rangle\langle n|+h.c.
$$
where $G=(V, E)$ is a *cyclic* graph (for which the rotating frame transformation typically fails)?

**Edit:**
For example, one approximation is simply to prune the graph until it becomes acyclic, as [Baker et al. (2008) Phys. Rev. A **98**, 052111](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevA.98.052111) do in an adaptive scheme that cleverly chooses which edges to remove in an attempt to minimize error. This is an idea first suggested by [Einwohner, Wong, and Garrison (1976) Phys. Rev. A **14**, 1452](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevA.14.1452). But I do wonder if there are other transformations/approximations that can be used for this problem.

---

**Context:**

Say we have a Hamiltonian with on-state energies as well as oscillating interaction terms, such that
$$
H=\sum_n \omega_n |n\rangle\langle n| + 
\sum_{(m,n)\in E,\ m<n}\left(
\Omega_{mn} e^{-i\omega_{L_{mn}} t} + 
\tilde\Omega_{mn}e^{i\omega_{L_{mn}} t}
\right)|m\rangle\langle n|+h.c.
$$
where the pairs $E$ can be viewed as the edges of some graph $G=(V,E)$, the vertices in $V$ being identified with ordered state labels (e.g. $V\subset\mathbb{Z^*}$). (Note: we have set $\hbar = 1$.)

After the typical transformation into the interaction picture and the rotating wave approximation, we are left with the approximation $$
\begin{align}
H_{1,I}^{RWA} &= \sum_{(m,n)\in E,\ m<n}\Omega_{mn} e^{-i(\omega_{L_{mn}}-\omega_n+\omega_m) t} |m\rangle\langle n|+h.c.\\
&= \sum_{(m,n)\in E,\ m<n}\Omega_{mn} e^{-i\Delta_{mn} t} |m\rangle\langle n|+h.c.
\end{align}
$$

The rotating frame transformation (RFT) (explained in [Whaley & Light (1984)](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevA.29.1188))
can, via a unitary transformation with a diagonal matrix $U^{RFT}$ whose diagonal $U^{RFT}_{mm}=e^{iq_{m}t}$ satisfies $q_{m} - q_{n} = -\Delta_{mn}$, cancel out the remaining time dependence, but in general only when the graph $G$ is *acyclic*.

This is because for *cyclic* graphs, for each cycle we have conditions $\Delta_{ab}+\Delta_{bc}+\ldots+\Delta_{fg}+\Delta_{ga}=0$ (for the edges $(a,b),\ (b,c)\ldots(g,a)$ that contribute to the cycle) that, if violated, mean the RFT cannot cancel the time dependence for all transitions in the loop.

Comment: I would add that in the past I've tried to peruse [Gabitov & Marshall (1998) Nonlinearity 11 845](https://doi.org/10.1088/0951-7715/11/4/006) as a way to perform a further approximation, as their Example (a) in 1.1 is precisely the first order approximation of adding a *single* extra term (+ h.c.). But I did not understand it well enough to generalize to additional terms or higher orders.